# Call a web service with MKNetworkoperation

Tags: xcode, web-services, mknetworkkit

In our development team we have implemented a WEB Service which will authenticate a client. 
From the iPhone application we need to send the client's information to the web service and in order to do so, I have written the following function.

```
-(void)authenticateClient:(NSString*)theContractNumber
           ClientCode:(NSString*)theClientCode
            CellPhone:(NSString*)theCellPhone
              appleID:(NSString*)theAppleID

{
NSLog(@"Begin Send the information to the Web Service",nil);

NSString *uid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;


NSDictionary *formParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            theClientCode, @"ClientCode",
                            theContractNumber, @"ContractCode",
                            theAppleID, @"AppleID",
                            @" ", @"AndroidID",
                            @" ", @"WindowsID",
                            uid, @"AppleDeviceID",
                            @" ", @"AndroidDeviceID",
                            @" ", @"WindowsDeviceID",
                            theCellPhone, @"TelephoneNumber"
                            , nil];

MKNetworkOperation *operation = [self.engine operationWithPath:@"/services/Authentication.ashx"
                                                        params: formParams
                                                    httpMethod:@"POST"];
[operation addCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKNetworkOperation *operation) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [operation responseString]);
 }
                   errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *errorOperation, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"%@", error);
                   }];
[self.engine enqueueOperation:operation] ;


}
```

the function works (or seems to works with no errors) but in fact it does not do anything. It passes from the **[operation addCompletionHandler:** block but it does not do anything. I have also executed it step by step and again I saw that the application reaches this line and then it executes it and directly goes to the **[self.engine enqueueOperation:operation]** line without going inside the code block.

Does anyone can help on this?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not want to believe that no-one uses MKNetworkKit?

Comment: code block in addCompletionHandler will called after response receive from the server.